# Clear caching in AFNetwork

Tags: json, caching, ios7, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

Trying to get some data from JSON file using AFHTTPRequestOperation, there is no issue at all in this part and everything is working smooth, what I want is to clear caching or to stop caching in this request, Why I want to do this is when anyone edit JSON file it will take a while "aprox 5 min" till it got updated in the clint side, So is it possible to Clear or stop caching for this request only..!?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set the cache policy for that request so it always loads the newest data.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData;
```

Comment: I already tried this option but same thing need to wait 5 min or more till it getting update, I suspect some caching in the Apache level or anything in that side which i'm not aware of it :(

Comment: one more thing I notice is that while I'm refreshing my app to get the latest JSON file, if I open the JSON file in the browser immediately it will be reflecting in my APP, I cannot understand what that mean